# Button doesn't work in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So I have tried to create a button from php that will be displayed in html and I tried to test the button by creating alert function but it doesn't work while if I create button in html directly the function works. Here is my code, which may not be clear, but I hope it helps with the understanding of my question. Thanks.

```
<?php 
echo"<div class='col-md-3'>";
echo"<p><button id='remove'>remove</button></p>";
?>

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#remove").click(function(){
        alert("test");

});
});
```

Comment: can you define what doesn't work?

Comment: remove button which is created in php. It's suppose to alert but it doesn't

Comment: You're using jquery, did you add that to your page?

Comment: Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported?

Comment: Your JS needs to be in a <script>   </script tag if you are in a php file

Comment: do you have any script tags around that javascript?

Comment: @Shogunivar   yea jquery file is added in html and also the library as well. No errors reported.

Comment: Are you adding more than one of these?

Comment: @JayBlanchard yes

Comment: [ID's Must Be Unique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme), specifically because it will cause problems in [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) and CSS when you try to interact with those elements.

Comment: @Shogunivar no it's not.

Comment: btw; you did close off your `<div>`, right? I don't see `</div>` anywhere

Comment: @JayBlanchard Does it matter if they are in session variable because i am creating shopping cart and every item will have remove button but for now i am actually testing if the button responds so i created alert function but didn't work. although the button exist.

Comment: `store_items.php?del` relevant? `//$.post('store_items.php?del',function(data){` that's commented out and there's no closing brace for `$(document).ready(function(){`. and that alone should have thrown you an error in dev console.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yea i did. The above code is a snippet.

Comment: oh; I see. not full code. awrighty then.

Comment: ok; I'm out; I'll have to pass on this, sorry

Comment: You're storing the markup in session variables?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Those items are stored in session variable and button beside them. So when i want to remove one item, i just click the button and remove it.

Comment: @insertusernamehere no it's not. I am creating button separately in php that will be displayed in html.

Comment: And you don't have any `form`-element somewhere on that page, that is a parent of `button`?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
echo"<div class='col-md-3'>";
echo"<p><button id='remove'>remove</button></p>";
?>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#remove").click(function(){
    //$.post('store_items.php?del',function(data){
        alert("test");

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: i have included that library as well.

Comment: You still need the script tags around the jquery code

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add script tags around the javascript code.

```
  <script type="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#remove").click(function(){

    alert("test");

});
});
</script>
```

Also what type of file are you serving? is it a PHP file?

Comment: Welcome to SO. any clarification about the question should be asked in the comments section. Please see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/163589/338114) to understand when to post an answer and when to post a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I just think you have to put things in the correct orders and in the right place. Try to reorganize your code as follow :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#remove").click(function(){
    //$.post('store_items.php?del',function(data){
        alert("test");

});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<?php 
echo "<div class='col-md-3'>";
echo "<p><button id='remove'>remove</button></p>";
echo "</div>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

PS: I tried it and it work fine ;-)

Hope be helpfull good luck for the next